# Main panel neutral to ground

Tags: breaker-box

There is a log for a number for copper wire  to the neutral lug is that connected to the ground? The number 4 is going to the grounding electrode outside[image]

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Can I run that copper wire through the ground bar on the box to the neutral lug besides the neutral?

Comment: Yes that is the main panel I just did not want to cut the copper wire if they are bonded I just thought it might as well be one wire. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

if this is your main panel not a sub yes you can